# Comparing a string in a struct with a string in an array

Tags: struct

I have an array of structs, one of the elements in the struct is a string, and i need to compare those strings with other strings in an array of 12 strings. strcmp does not seem to work for me. I know i need to make seperate function to compare the the strings and return the value as a bool, but cant figure out how to make the compare function work.

The struct

```
  typedef struct{
     char *hometeam[Max_number_of_chars], *awayteam[Max_number_of_chars];
     int  playround, date_day, date_month, date_year, 
          time_hour, time_minute, home_score, away_score, crowd_thousand,
          crowd_hundred; 
  } match;
```

The array of strings

```
    char *teams[Number_of_teams] = {"AGF","AAB","SDR","RFC",
                                    "EFB","BIF","SIF","OB",
                                    "FCK","FCM", "ACH","FCN"};
```

the line where i need the compare_function

```
    if(compare_names(all_games[i].hometeam, teams[j])==0) {//crazy stuff}
```

EDIT: What i need help with is making function that compares the string value from *teams[j] with the string value from all_games[i].hometeam. But i dont know how to pass the specific part of the struct all_games[i].hometeam to the compare_function, where i want it to be a char string.

Comment: PLEASE format the code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming  char *teams[Number_of_teams] is globally defined.
int find_match(struct match)
{
   for(i=0; i < Number_of_teams; i++){
       if(strcmpi(match.hometeam, teams[i]) == 0){
           return i;
       }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

The logical flow of what you want to do isn't clear, but you can try something like above.

Comment: Okay, maybe i wasn't clear enough with my logic, but the problem now comes down to that i am not sure how to transfer `all_teams[i].hometeam´ as a char * type to my function that should compare the strings in all_teams and from the strings from team[j]

Comment: You want the function to accept just the string and not the structure? Change- find_match(char *team). And the comparison now becomes- strcmpi(team, teams[i])

Comment: Yes i only want to receive the string part of the struct, but also i want the specific string at teams[i] as input aswell to the compare function, since i allready have a loop running through alle the i's and j's in another function, which should call the compare function. I keep getting an error where the compiler expects specifiers before the inputs